# Filtering Mongo items by multiple fields and subfields

Tags: mongodb

I have the following items in my collection:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("532c471a90bc7707609a3d4f"), "name" : "Alice" }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532c472490bc7707609a3d50"),
    "name" : "Bob",
    "partner_type1" : {
        "status" : "rejected"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532c473e90bc7707609a3d51"),
    "name" : "Carol",
    "partner_type2" : {
        "status" : "accepted"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532c475790bc7707609a3d52"),
    "name" : "Dave",
    "partner_type1" : {
        "status" : "pending"
    }
}
```

There are two *partner* types: `partner_type1` and `partner_type2`. A user cannot be *accepted* partner in the both of types. But he can be a rejected partner in `partner_type1` but accepted in the another, for example.

How can I build Mongo query that fetches the users that can become partners?

Comment: Sadly every query of any complexity looks like a map/reduce to me in terms of Mongo. Can you combine the partner_type fields into a single field that represents all possible states (like a bit flag field) and query against that instead? It could simplify the problem.

Comment: @cfeduke I would avoid map/reduce... If a query is not possible, merging the fields would be the solution. Can you post an answer, please?

Comment: Well: [MongoDB Bitwise Filtering](http://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/mongodb-bitwise-filtering-faster-status-querying-performance/) though it uses Javascript so I don't think you can take advantage of indexes. However depending on the number of `partner_type` statuses you have you can likely precalculate all of the integer values for all combinations of flags and use that to query with the benefits of an index.

Comment: How many statuses do you have? Three? `Accepted`, `Rejected`, and `Pending`?

Comment: @cfeduke Let's say yes. I guess I have more, but let's suppose we have only these.

Comment: Before going down a bit flags path (which probably isn't necessary, now that I'm engaging my brain muscle) - isn't your query all those users who aren't `Accepted` in either `partner_type` field? (You may need to revise your question if there are more requirements.)

Comment: @cfeduke The concept is: an user cannot be active (*Accepted*) partner  in both types. So, I need to fetch all the users. It should be simple to update their `status` value.

Comment: @cfeduke I think I will create a field named `partner` that will be an array of objects: `{type: "1/2", status: "..."}`. Then `$elemMatch` would work fine.

Comment: Is your desired output something like "Bob" is eligible to be partners with "Alice" (no `partner_type` at all) and "Dave" (no accepted `partner_type`s)? Or just a simple collection of all users who don't have a single `Accepted` `partner_type` status? Basically are you writing a query that gives you matches per user, or just all users eligible for a match?

Comment: @cfeduke The users are not linked between them. For my example, only `Alice` and `Bob` can become partners. `Carol` is already partner1 and  the status of Dave is unclear yet (pending). Have you got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your user can only be accepted in one partner-type, you should turn it around: Have a field `accepted_as:"partner_type1"` or `accepted_as:"partner_type2"`. For people who aren't accepted yet, either have no such field or set it to `null`.

In both cases, your query to get any non-accepted will then be:

```
{
   data.accepted_as: null
}
```

(null matches both non-existing fields as well as fields explicitly set to null)

Comment: @IonicăBizău I edited your edit, the query you suggested was much more convoluted than necessary.

Comment: Supposing that not all the users have `accepted_as` field your query will not work.

Comment: @IonicăBizău It will work: [`field:null`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls) matches all documents where the field is null **or** doesn't exist. When you want to match only (or exclude) documents without the field, there is also the [$exists operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) which can be used as `field:{$exists:true}` or `field:{$exists:false}`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the logical schema would be this:

```
"partner : {
    "type": 1,
    "status" : "rejected"
}
```

At least that keeps the paths consistent between documents.

So if you want to stay away from using mapReduce type methods to find out "which field" it is on, and otherwise use plain queries and the aggregation pipeline, then don't vary field paths on documents. If you alter the "data" then that is the most consistent form.